# Question about Imre Hermann's book Parallelismes

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, psychoanalysis

Apparently, in his book Parallelismes, Imre Hermann discusses Hilbert, Brouwer en Russell from the viewpoint of psycho-pathology. Does anyone know whether the entire book is about mathematicians/mathematics, or does this part only take up a chapter or a couple of pages or so, and the rest is about other subjects?